# How do I get values (multiple rows and columns) to be set in another sheet with the getLastRow?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a button in my sheet that should copy the ranges (found below, called 'values') into another sheet. The data should be placed in two columns and continue down the sheet with time when new data is sent. Therefore I try to use the getLastRow, however, I am not able to copy the ranges due to an error:

"Cannot copy C30:C51 to int"

Thanks for the help

```
function sendBudgetData() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var budget = ss.getSheetByName("BUDGET");
var budgettransaktion = ss.getSheetByName("BUDGETTRANSAKTIONER");

var values = [

[budget.getRange("C30:C51","H30:H51").getValues()],
[budget.getRange("C58:C64","H58:H64").getValues()],
[budget.getRange("C69:C72","H69:H72").getValues()]

];


//I want to set the values above in two columns.
budgettransaktion.getRange(budgettransaktion.getLastRow()+1,4,3,2).setValues(values);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of trying to attach the two columns together won't work in its current structure. You can accomplish this a couple ways (and there are probably more efficient ways than my solution), but this will work. I would suggest that you should consider using named ranges instead of hard coded cell addresses. Also make sure when you set values in your sheet, you have the proper number of rows which can be identified using `values.length`.

```
function sendBudgetData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var budget = ss.getSheetByName("BUDGET");
  var budgettransaktion = ss.getSheetByName("BUDGETTRANSAKTIONER");

  var firstColumn = budget.getRange("C30:C51").getValues().concat(
    budget.getRange("C58:C64").getValues(),
    budget.getRange("C69:C72").getValues());

  var secondColumn = budget.getRange("H30:H51").getValues().concat(
    budget.getRange("H58:H64").getValues(),
    budget.getRange("H69:H72").getValues());

  //you now have two arrays with value. Te below loop will run through all elements and push them
  // into the values array with the propery structure of two values per row.
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < firstColumn.length; i++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < firstColumn[0].length; c++) {
      values.push([firstColumn[i][c], secondColumn[i][c]]);
    }
  }

  //set the values in your spreadsheet. Not to make sure to use the length of values.
  //Your prior code only allowed for three rows.
  budgettransaktion.getRange(budgettransaktion.getLastRow() + 1, 4, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to include two additional columns to the left, they should also follow the getLastRow rule? If it's possible I would like to have one column that takes a single value from the cell ("Budget! B7") and sets that value to all corresponding rows in the column. The same thing goes for the other column, however, that column shall take its value from ("Budget! E7"). To sum up, Four columns, the first one (takes value from B7), the second one (takes value from E7), third and fourth (already completed, what you recently solved) and all follow the getLastRow rule.